# How to use a subquery in postgresql using R

Tags: r, postgresql

```
   query2 <- dbGetQuery(con,paste0("select uniqueno from 
    postgres.asset where location_id in (",dbGetQuery(con,"select 
    location_id from postgres.location where city_name 
    ='",cityname,"')")
```

both the tables postgres.asset and postgres.location are postgres Table.
Error it shows for the inner query , as it is unable to find the connection 
parameter.

Do let me know how to get rid of the error. I doubt the error comes for the misplacing of `paste0` command

Comment: are both tables in the same database?

Comment: "cityname" is my input and its a R variable, hence i have to use paste0 command

Comment: Yes both are in the same database

Comment: can you try something like this? `query2 <- dbGetQuery(con,paste0("select uniqueno from 
    postgres.asset where location_id in (select 
    location_id from postgres.location where city_name 
    ='",cityname,"')")`

Comment: i tried first with that, but it says , "Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  relation "postgres.location" does not exist

Comment: i doubt, in the inner query i am not passing the connection parameter. if i can pass connection in both outer and inner , then that might help

Comment: Normally you wouldn't need to create a second conn for firing a subquery. Are you sure that the table `location` is indeed at the schema `postgres`?

Comment: Yes, it is in the postgres

Comment: That's weird. Well, assuming you're not confusing a `schema` with a `database`, there is not much we can do. Keep in mind that even the database `postgres` (normally a maintenance db) also has a **schema** called `public`. Good luck!

Comment: Maybe omit the (funny) schema name entirely: `query2 <- dbGetQuery(con, paste0("select uniqueno from asset where location_id in (select location_id from location where city_name ='", cityname, "');")`

Comment: @joop that would be also my suspicion ;-) +1

Answer (score 0):

```
    locationid <- dbGetQuery(con, paste0("select location_id from postgres.location where city_name = '",cityname ,"'"))

    for(i in 1:nrow(locationid)){
    uniqueid <- dbGetQuery(con, paste0("select uniqueno from postgres.asset where location_id = '",locationid[i,],"'"))}
```